# How to create short and long term database objectives

Tags: sql-server

I'm at a new employer and I have been asked to create short term and long term database objectives.

I've reviewed several databases and can see they lack referential integrity and will need additional indexes, daily backups and maintenance appear sufficient. I recognize these as a short term goal/objectives. But I having trouble with long term goals and want to be prepared for a meeting next week. I'm looking any suggestions/direction on creating such a list.

Comment: Security could be one of them.

Comment: I think a naming standard for objects and columns is helpful as a long term objective.